# Set parent class's attribute in child class through constructor

Tags: inheritance, typescript2.0

I have the following parent class.

```js
class SomeType {}

abstract class Parent {
    protected element : SomeType;

    protected constructor() {
        this.element = this.getElement();
    }

    public abstract getElement() : SomeType;
}
```

The parent class contains an element which exists in all child implementation. But the way how I can get this element is different in each child implementation. Maybe I'm trying to solve this originally wrong.

Here is the example of the child class:

```js
class Child extends Parent{
    public constructor(
        protected readonly selector : string
    ) {
        super();
    }

    public getElement() : SomeType {
        return someMagicalGetter(this.selector);
    }
}
```

The point is:
The `super()` gets called before `this.selector` is being set. But I need the value of the `this.selector` in the `getElement` method.

**Question:** Is there a better approach to solve this? (I guess there is but then how?)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution I figured out:

```js
abstract class Parent {
    protected element : SomeType;

    protected constructor(selector : string) {
        this.element = this.getElement(selector);
    }

    public abstract getElement(selector) : SomeType;
}

class Child extends Parent{
    public constructor(
        protected readonly selector : string
    ) {
        super(selector);
    }

    public getElement(selector : string) : SomeType {
        return someMagicalGetter(selector);
    }
}
```

Actually the example above solves, for this use case. But actually its not a good solution if the child has more then one parameter which are being used in the method `getElement`.

**EDIT:**

The following I decided to use:

```js
abstract class Parent {
    protected constructor(protected readonly element : SomeType) { }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    public constructor(
        protected readonly selector : string
    ) {
        super(someMagicalGetter(selector));
    }
}
```

I overcomplicated it a bit.